# Threaded low latency audio on Android

Tags: android, audio, pthreads, low-latency

The short version:
I'm developing a synth app and using Opensl with low latency. I was doing all the audio calculation in the Opensl callback funktion (I know I should not but I did anyway). Now the calculations take about 75% cpu time on my nexus 4, so the next step is to do all the calculations in multiple threads instead.

The problem I ran into was that the audio started to stutter since the callback thread obviously run on a high priority while my new thread doesn't. If I use more/bigger buffers the problem goes away but so does the realtime too. Setting higher priority on the new thread don't seem to work. 
So, is there even possible to do threaded low latency audio or do I have to do everything in the callback for it to work?

I have a buffer of 256 samples and that's about 5ms and that should be ages for the thread- scheduler-thingie to run my calc thread.

Comment: Why do you say you shouldn't do all the audio calculation in the callback? I'm not familiar with Opensl, but in most audio libraries that's exactly what you DO want to do. It's things that blocking for arbitrary amounts of time (like I/O) that you must avoid.

Comment: @Bjorn Roche: If it's low latency you're after,  you have to do the synthesis in the callback. If you do it asynchronously, you need more buffering and will end up doubling the system latency.

Comment: Every tutorial i have read said that i should perform very little tasks in the callback. And a actually managed to crash android (to the point where the white text with "Google" comes up), and it was reproducable every time i put too much processing in the callback.  And in openSL, the callback just say that it wants more data before the buffer runs out, so i should have time enough to wake another thread to do the work. I mean, on a quadcore phone, at least one core should be idling and ready for some munber crunching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem lies in the performance of your synth-engine.   A decent channel count with a Cortex-A8 or -A9 CPU is achievable with a single core.   What language have you implemented it in?  If it happens to be Java, I recommend porting it to C++.

Using multiple threads for synthesis is certainly possible, but brings with it new problems - namely that each thread must synchronise before the generated audio can be mixed.

Unless you take an additional latency hit that would come from running the synthesis threads asynchronously, the likely set-up is that in your render call-back you'd signal the additional synthesis threads and then wait for them to complete before mixing the audio from all of them together.

(an obvious optimisation is that the render call-back runs some of the processing itself as it's already running on the CPU and would otherwise be doing nothing).

Herein lies the problem.  Unless you can be certain that your synth render threads run with real-time priority, you can potentially take a scheduling hit each time the render callback runs, and potentially another if you block the callback thread waiting for the synth render threads to catch up.

Last time I looked at audio on Android, Bionic was deficient of a means of setting real-time thread priority (e.g. `SCHED_FIFO`). In any case,  whether this is even allowed is matter of operating system policy: on a desktop Linux system you either need to be root or have adjusted the appropriate `ulimit` (as root) - I'm not sure what Android does here, but I very much suspect that downloaded apps aren't by default given this permission. Nor the other useful permission which is to `mlock()` the code and its likely stack needs into physical memory.

Comment: Yes, it's written in C++ and yes, one instance of the engine can run on one core. The idea is (was?) to run multiple instances of the synth where the other instances would be triggered by a sequencer. That's why I need the extra computing power. But on the other hand, I could probably calc/render them a few buffers ahead, and just deal with the main synth instance in the callback.

Comment: And you are right about the thread priority, an app can only lower it's priority, not raise it. I guess i'm a bit frustrated since the callback thread runs with high priority.

Comment: @Floaf:  That approach would work fine - in fact, you can pre-calculate quite a bit. 

You might consider whether your synth engine can be parallelized by rendering two voices at once - you'd probably get much better utilisation of NEON that way.  There are in any case lots of cheap wins to be had.  One further bit of advice: If you've got an iPad or iPhone handy, Apple's profiling tools are *way* better than anything on Android - you can literally profile down to the instruction level  and do find the expensive parts of your algorithm - knowing the results will be close for other ARM devices.

Comment: I've been looking into NEON a bit since for example, the reverb algorithm, consumes about 12% cpu power and thats not ok. And it would be fun to learn NEON. My only concern is that I have to do the same for Intels processors in recent phones. So much to learn, so little time.

Comment: @Floaf I'd advise you to try an optimise as much as possible in C/C++ to avoid precisely this issue. However, to be fair, there aren't many x86 phones out there, and this doesn't seem likely to change any time soon.

Comment: I agree in that a C/C++ optimization is optimal. If you are using an auto-vectorizing compiler you might be able to rely on some of your audio processing loops which are highly vectorizable to be NEON registered.

Comment: The problem with multithreaded is that you obviously cant have interdependence of the audio data between threads. Its like a one way trip to mars. When the threads join you still have to mix down the buffers. Waiting for these threads to join might cost you.